# Change the title of the AmChart

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am changing datesets of the charts when having certaint condition in if cause.
So chart bars shows dataset by day or by month. I want to change the title of the chart when I repaint the chart. I can't add additional valueAxis later, because it's already there, but somehow title to different want. I want to do something like this `chart.valueAxis.title = "Title #2"`But it doesn't work. How to reach that variable in chart?

Example:http://jsfiddle.net/u3ypB/516/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access at your valueAxis and change his title attribute

For example : chart.valueAxes[0].title = "foo"

Comment: Thanks. I have just figured out that I can console.log(chart) and to walk in the object

Comment: Yes ! use console.log anytime this is a useful function

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(d==0) {
                chart.valueAxes[0].title = "Title #1";
  } else {
             chart.valueAxes[0].title = "Title #2";
  }
```

See this  > http://jsfiddle.net/dadmand/u3ypB/1157/